# How to populate a DropDownList based on another DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing a Sales Order based on the list of projects.
I got two Drop Down List. The First drop down list retrieve data from the Projects Table. The Second drop down list is to populate data based on the selected value from the First Drop Down List.

Below shows the source code for the drop down list for both projects and task.

---

```
    <!--Project-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">
            Project</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProjects" runat="server" class="form-control" 
                AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="Select a project..." DataValueField="AutoId" 
                onselectedindexchanged="ddlProjects_SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Tasks-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">
            Task</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTasks" runat="server" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

Below shows the code behind the Drop Down List

---

```
void GetProjects()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ProjectID, Name FROM Projects WHERE Status = 'On Going'";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ddlProjects.DataSource = dr;
    ddlProjects.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddlProjects.DataValueField = "ProjectID";
    ddlProjects.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}

protected void ddlProjects_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    var ID = int.Parse(ddlProjects.SelectedValue);

    string sql = "SELECT TaskID, Name FROM ProjectTasks WHERE ProjectID = @ProjectID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", ID);
    ad.Fill(table);
    ddlTasks.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddlTasks.DataSource = table;
    ddlTasks.DataBind();
}
```

---

The problem is that everytime i open the Sales Order Form, the default DataTextValue is not the one I declared in the source code which is "Select a Project" but instead it shows the first record.

Another thing is that I feel that there is still something wrong with the code I just cannot identify which is it.

Let me know if you have any clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove `DataTextField="Select a project..." DataValueField="AutoId"` from your aspx. You're defining this in your code.

Add your first option and set `AppendDataBoundItems = true`

```
ddlProjects.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select a project...",""));
ddlProjects.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
ddlProjects.DataSource = dr;
ddlProjects.DataTextField = "Name";
ddlProjects.DataValueField = "ProjectID";
ddlProjects.DataBind();
```

Make sure the empty item isnt selected

```
protected void ddlProjects_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlTasks.Items.Clear();
    int ID = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(ddlProjects.SelectedValue, out ID))
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        string sql = "SELECT TaskID, Name FROM ProjectTasks WHERE ProjectID = @ProjectID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", ID);
        ad.Fill(table);
        ddlTasks.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlTasks.DataSource = table;
        ddlTasks.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but then everytime I select back the "Select a project..." value I get an error at
"var ID = int.Parse(ddlProjects.SelectedValue);"
Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: best option is to check the selected value in `ddlProjects_SelectedIndexChanged` and make sure it's valid and clear the `ddlTasks` if not.

Comment: sorry I dont get that one.

Comment: Thanks it work very well, just what I'm looking for  :) I just edited some alignments